# Changing the color of a word in a TextField in javafx

Tags: java, javafx

I have a TextField(JavaFX) whose text color is black, but if the word warning was in the text, it would come and only change the color of the word warning to red.

Comment: JavaFX text input controls do not support styling for portions of the text. Consider either using a web component (such as a `WebView` or `HTMLEditor`) or a third party library (such as [Rich Text FX](https://github.com/FXMisc/RichTextFX))

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaFX text input controls do not support multiple styles for different parts of the text. One way to do that is to use a third-party library that provides that functionality. The RichTextFX library contains some styled text area classes that do this. Here is a brief example of using this library for something similar to what you describe:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import org.fxmisc.richtext.StyleClassedTextArea;
import org.fxmisc.wellbehaved.event.EventPattern;
import org.fxmisc.wellbehaved.event.InputMap;
import org.fxmisc.wellbehaved.event.Nodes;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        StyleClassedTextArea textArea = new StyleClassedTextArea();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("warning");
        textArea.textProperty().addListener((obs, oldText, text) -> {
            textArea.clearStyle(0, textArea.getLength());
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
            while (matcher.find()) {
                textArea.setStyleClass(matcher.start(), matcher.end(), "warning");
            }
        });
        textArea.replaceText("This text area will highlight the word warning in any text");
        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(textArea);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

style.css:

```
.warning {
    -fx-fill:red;
}
```

Here is a portion of the `pom.xml` that provides the RichTextFX library:

```
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>sonatype</id>
            <url>https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>20.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.fxmisc.richtext</groupId>
            <artifactId>richtextfx</artifactId>
            <version>0.11.1</version>
        </dependency>

    <!-- ... -->
    </dependencies>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple program ...

We add a listener to the TextField. When its text changes to `warning`, we add the style class "warning" to it. The text color can now be easily changed to red.

**Code:**

```
public class TestfieldStyle extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        TextField field = new TextField();

        field.textProperty().addListener((p,o,n) -> {
            if(n.equals("warning")) {
                field.getStyleClass().add("warning");
            } else {
                field.getStyleClass().remove("warning");
            }
        });

        VBox root = new VBox(field);
        root.getStylesheets().add("/textfield.css");

        stage.setScene(new Scene(root,500,500));
        stage.show();
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
.text-field.warning {
    -fx-text-fill: red;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question: *"if the word warning was **in** the text"* (not "if the text is equal to the word warning") *"and **only** change the color of the word warning"* (my emphasis). So the intention is to only style *part* of the text, not the entire control.